# Jenkins - docker: not found

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, raspberry-pi

I'm pretty new to do docker and jenkins but wanted to see if I could get a node app automatically deployed and running on my raspberry pi. In an ideal world, I'd like to have Jenkins pull down code from github, use a jenkinsfile and dockerfile to build and run the docker image (hopefully this is possible).

**jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile true
    }
    environment {
        CI = 'true' 
        HOME = '.'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Install dependencies') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') { 
            steps {
                sh './scripts/test' 
            }
        }
        stage('Build Container') { 
            steps {
                sh 'docker build -t test-app:${BUILD_NUMBER} . ' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**dockerfile**

```
 # Create image based on the official Node image
FROM node:12

# Create a directory where our app will be placed
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY package.json /usr/src/app

# Install dependecies
RUN npm install

# Get all the code needed to run the app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 3000

# Serve the app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

However, when I try to run this in jenkins, I get the following error: *../script.sh: docker: not found*. This seems to be the case for any docker command. I actually tried running some other command starting with 'sudo' and it complained that *sudo: not found*. Is there a step missing or am I trying to do something in an incorrect way. (NOTE: docker is installed on the raspberry pi. I can log in with the jenkins user and execute docker commands. It just doesn't work through the web ui) Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Jenkins commands are executed with Jenkins user created automatically by the installer.  Try to login as Jenkins user using sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins and then trying to execute docker commands? My guess is that Jenkins user don't have access to docker system. Could you please verify this? The problem is not most likely in your scripts file but the system you are trying to execute it. UPDATE: sorry I noticed you already tried this. Did you add the Jenkins user to Dockergroup?

Comment: Add Jenkins user to docker groups and then restart Jenkins system?

Comment: Yup, if I run 'groups jenkins' I get: 'jenkins : jenkins sudo docker'. Looks like it's part of the 'docker' group. Note: I have recently restarted the jenkins service as well

Comment: Did you install it manually or with the Docker plugin? You could try if this plugin solves the problem https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-plugin/ Otherwise I think your system still can't access the docker socket which is also happening on my laptop. You could try something like: sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/run/docker.sock not sure if this works though. It must be something related to not be able to connect to the docker socket.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what this does, but I have to run this command every time on my Xubuntu system before I can start docker locally sudo setfacl -m user:$USER:rw /var/run/docker.sock This script works for me so you could also try to login with the jenkins user and execute this command

Comment: Print the system path in the pipeline, before executing the docker command. Maybe this variable is being set incorrectly

Comment: What am I looking for when printing path? Also, I tried running some of those commands and got errors: "command setfacl not found" when SSH'd into the device (must not have something installed). and "./script.sh: sudo: not found" when the pipeline runs. Any other suggestions?... I'm about out of ideas...

Comment: I will also add that when I run the "chown -R" from above, without sudo, I get invalid user: 'jenkins:jenkins'. Does this build agent live on an entirely different spectrum as everything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this section was breaking it:

```
agent {
    dockerfile true
}
```

When I set this:

```
agent any
```

it finished the build, including docker commands without any issues. I guess I just don't understand how that piece works. Any explanations would be helpful!